# BSP Dungeon Generator giving an unfixable error

Tags: ios, swift, actionscript-3, sprite-kit, actionscript

I'm working on translating [this ActionScript tutorial](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-bsp-trees-to-generate-game-maps--gamedev-12268) on binary space partitioning into Swift so I can use it in my rogue-like game. I came across a hitch.

In the article, the writer initializes his class like so:

```
public function Leaf(X:int, Y:int, Width:int, Height:int)
{
    // initialize our leaf
    x = X;
    y = Y;
    width = Width;
    height = Height;
}
```

When I translated this into Swift, I ran into an error. The code above doesn't initialize all its declared values. This leads me into an impossible error that I can't seem to fix. Somehow, the writer of the article initializes his `leftChild` and `rightChild` variables with this function that is outside the initialization scope.

```
public function split():Boolean
{
    // begin splitting the leaf into two children
    if (leftChild != null || rightChild != null)
        return false; // we're already split! Abort!

    // determine direction of split
    // if the width is >25% larger than height, we split vertically
    // if the height is >25% larger than the width, we split horizontally
    // otherwise we split randomly
    var splitH:Boolean = FlxG.random() > 0.5;
    if (width > height && width / height >= 1.25)
        splitH = false;
    else if (height > width && height / width >= 1.25)
        splitH = true;

    var max:int = (splitH ? height : width) - MIN_LEAF_SIZE; // determine the maximum height or width
    if (max <= MIN_LEAF_SIZE)
        return false; // the area is too small to split any more...

    var split:int = Registry.randomNumber(MIN_LEAF_SIZE, max); // determine where we're going to split

    // create our left and right children based on the direction of the split
    if (splitH)
    {
        leftChild = new Leaf(x, y, width, split);
        rightChild = new Leaf(x, y + split, width, height - split);
    }
    else
    {
        leftChild = new Leaf(x, y, split, height);
        rightChild = new Leaf(x + split, y, width - split, height);
    }
    return true; // split successful!
}
```

Which is somehow ok in ActionScript, but in Swift it leads me to my problem.

Here is my translated code (Swift):

```
private let mapWidth:Int = 50
private let mapHeight:Int = 50

class Leaf {
    var leftLeaf = [Leaf]()
    var rightLeaf = [Leaf]()

    var minLeafSize:Int = 6
    var x, y, width, height: Int

    var leftChild:Leaf
    var rightChild:Leaf

    init (X:Int, Y:Int, W:Int, H:Int) {

        x = Y
        y = Y

        width = W
        height = H

        let maxLeafSize:UInt = 20

        var leaves = [Leaf]()

        // first, create a Leaf to be the 'root' of all Leafs.
        let root = Leaf(X: 0, Y: 0, W: mapWidth, H: mapHeight)
        leaves.append(root)

        var didSplit:Bool = true
        // we loop through every Leaf in our Vector over and over again, until no more Leafs can be split.
        while (didSplit) {
            didSplit = false
            for l in leaves {
                if l.leftLeaf.isEmpty == true && l.rightLeaf.isEmpty == true {
                    // if this Leaf is too big, or 75% chance...
                    if l.width > maxLeafSize || l.height > maxLeafSize || Int(arc4random_uniform(100)) > 25 {
                        if (l.split()) {
                            // if we did split, push the child leafs to the Vector so we can loop into them next
                            leaves.append(l.leftChild)
                            leaves.append(l.rightChild)
                            didSplit = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    func split() -> Bool {
        if leftLeaf.isEmpty == true || rightLeaf.isEmpty == true {
            return false
        }

        var splitH = arc4random_uniform(100) > 50 ? true : false

        if width > height && Double(width / height) >= 1.25 {
            splitH = false
        }
        if height > width && Double(height / width) >= 1.25 {
            splitH = true
        }

        let max:Int = (splitH ? height : width) - minLeafSize // determine the maximum height or width
        if max <= minLeafSize { return false }

        let split:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(minLeafSize - max) + UInt32(max)))

        if (splitH) {
            leftChild = Leaf(X: x, Y: y, W: width, H: split)
            rightChild = Leaf(X: x, Y: y + split, W: width, H: height - split)

            leftLeaf.append(leftChild)
            rightLeaf.append(rightChild)
        } else {
            leftChild = Leaf(X: x, Y: y, W: split, H: height)
            rightChild = Leaf(X: x + split, Y: y, W: width - split, H: height);

            leftLeaf.append(leftChild)
            rightLeaf.append(rightChild)
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

It is identical (as far as I can figure) to the ActionScript code in the article. But it is giving me an error. The `leftChild` and `rightChild` variables aren't initialized in my `init` method. When I move the `split() -> Bool` function into the `init` method it won't let me use the function, giving me an error "Value of type Leaf has no member split()". Removing the `l` from the `if (l.spit())` line gives me a second error "Use of local variable 'split' before its declaration". The `split()` function has to be outside the initialization scope.

If I attempt to initialize `leftChild` and `rightChild` like so:

```
init (X:Int, Y:Int, W:Int, H:Int) {

    x = Y
    y = Y

    width = W
    height = H

    leftChild = Leaf(X: x, Y: y, W: width, H: height)
    rightChild = Leaf(X: x, Y: y, W: width, H: height)
}
```

It creates an infinite loop that eventually causes a crash.

The code should be initializing `leftChild` and `rightChild` in the `split() -> Bool` function but I don't think that's how it works in Swift. You should be able to copy/paste it into a Swift file and get the same errors.

Why is this happening? Is my code poorly written? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ActionScript, uninitialised variables are automatically evaluated with the special value `undefined`; also, in ActionScript, `undefined == null`, which is why `if (leftChild != null || rightChild != null)` works.

In Swift, you need to explicitly [allow](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional) your variables to be nilable. The variables you are worried about need to start off as `nil` (which they automatically will, if you allow them to, by setting their type to `Optional` - note the question mark):

```
var leftChild:Leaf?
var rightChild:Leaf?
```

Comment: Quick answer! I couldn't figure out how the writer had done his code. I fixed my code based off of your answer and it seems to be working now. I've never studied any ActionScript before. So it would have been impossible for me to figure this out by myself.